Slow Leak at Brass Fitting on Hot Water Line (Kitchen Sink)
I have a slow leak under my kitchen sink. It is from the hot water line to the faucet and dishwasher. I have tried replacing the brass fitting but it still leaks in the same spot. You can see the drip under the nut on the left. How do I stop the drip?
Thanks!






If you have replaced the brass fitting and the leak persists, the likely culprit is the white plastic fitting it connects to where the leak is. Plastic fittings can easily be scratched or scored and won't seal properly as a result of any such damage.

Do you know what that white plastic fitting is called?

A (cheap and shoddy, IMHO) shutoff valve (sometimes aka "stop valve") You'll need to shut off the water coming to it to change it - might be a manifold valve (being PEX, apparently) or might mean shutting off the main water valve for the house.

@Ecnerwal agreed.  Fortunately, it looks like a simple press-on supply valve, and should be easily removed and replaced with a Sharkbyte (or similar) valve.  Looks like CPVC pipe.

It was the plastic fitting I just put on a new metal shark bite one and I no longer have the leak! Thanks everyone!
